# Data is not displayed at front end react with graphql queries at node.js backend

Tags: reactjs, node.js, graphql, frontend, backend

github link -> https://github.com/hemantgit21/graphql

GET_CLIENTS Query screenshot at backend graphql - [image]

React frontend components - ClientQueries.jsx

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

const GET_CLIENTS = gql`
  query getClients {
    clients {
      id
      name
      email
      phone
    }
  }
`;

export { GET_CLIENTS };
```

clientMutation.jsx

```
import {gql} from '@apollo/client';  
const DELETE_CLIENT = gql`  mutation deleteClient($id: ID!) {          
deleteClient(id:$id) {
 id 
name
 email
 phone 
  } } `;
 export {DELETE_CLIENT};
```

Client.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import ClientRow from './ClientRow';
import { GET_CLIENTS } from './queries/clientQueries';

export default function Client({ id }) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_CLIENTS, {
    variables: { id },
  });

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;
  }

 

  return (
    <table className="table table-hover mt-3">
      <tbody>
        {data.clients.map((client) => (
          <ClientRow key={client.id} client={client} />
        ))}
        

         </tbody>
 </table>
  );
}
```

ClientRow.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { DELETE_CLIENT } from './mutations/clientMutation'
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/client'
import { GET_CLIENTS } from './queries/clientQueries'

export default function ClientRow({client}) {

 const [deleteClient] = useMutation(DELETE_CLIENT,{
    variables:{id:client.id},
    refetchQueries:[{query:GET_CLIENTS}],
    update(cache,{data:{deleteClient}}) {
     const {clients} = cache.readQuery({query:GET_CLIENTS});
     cache.writeQuery({
        query:GET_CLIENTS,
        data:{clients:clients.filter(client=>client.id!==deleteClient.id),},
     })   
    }
 });

  return (
    <div>
      <tr>
        <td>{client.name}</td>
        <td>{client.email}</td>
        <td>{client.phone}</td>
         <td>
            <button onClick={deleteClient}>Delete</button>
         </td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  )
}
```

data is not displayed from mongodb using graphql in frontend react , however the query is running in backend localhost server . I want to run the react application and backend with graphQL query and APIs to fetch data from Mongodb. The data from mongodb database is not displayed help me regarding this.

Comment: Please show the `clients` query code from the server as well as the schema definition of that query. Odds are you're not returning the results from the server correctly.

Comment: what is clients query code ?

Comment: Can you help me with this?

Comment: The backend part is running properly on localhost:3000/graphql  and data is getting saved into MongoDB database in front end react I am facing error in map function {data.clients.map((client) => (
          <ClientRow key={client.id} client={client} />
        ))}  (screenshot of backend attached)

Comment: Your front end looks ok but I suspect `data.clients` is `[]` which would point towards your query resolver not returning a valid array of clients.

Comment: Should I upload the code on GitHub?

Comment: github link - https://github.com/hemantgit21/graphql

Answer (score 0):

1. Could you share how do you did the configurations of your graphql client?
   your problem it's not cleary. I presumed that data is not showing ina file  Clients.tsx, right?
2. I  would recommend you to use useState to storage the clients, and one useeffect to update:

```
const [clients, setClients] = React.useState([])
React.useEffect(()=> {
  if(data?.clients){
  setClients(data.clients);
}
},[data])

// NOw your render:
return (
    <table className="table table-hover mt-3">
      <tbody>
        {clients.map((client) => (
          <ClientRow key={client.id} client={client} />
        ))}
        

         </tbody>
 </table>
  );
```

if you wanna refresh the list after mutation delete... I would do like this:
create a method on Clients.tsx to remove on client lists:
`Clients.tsx`

```
function removeClient(client) {
  const newClients = clients.filter((item) => item.id !== client.id)
  setClients(newClients);
}

// and pass this method throught

<clientRow key={client.id} client={client} removeClient={removeClient} />
```

if server confirm deletion, For me no make sense request the server one more time. I prefer just to do the client update the list. When the user request again will see the same list without that client.

usually I use Context to manage all methods, lists, and operation from entities like that. to not using component parameters for everything.